# Change <div> innerText from NestedMasted Page so that the Changed text remains throughout session

Tags: master-pages

I want to change the inner text value of a div that is located on my site.master page, and I want the changed value to remain for the rest of the session.

The value I want to pull through is the User name that is obtained from OAuth
By Using: `User.Identity.Name;`

I can only access this property once a user has authenticated, based on my redirect after authentication the page then moves to a nested master page for the members_only section.
I can change the text of the div with this code:

```
((HtmlGenericControl)Master.Master.FindControl("LoginButton")).InnerText = User.Identity.Name;
```

But as soon as I redirect, the text changes back to null.

I use it for my bootstrap user button which looks like this

```
                        <div class="btn-group">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i>&nbsp;<div id="LoginButton" runat="server"></div></a><a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="caret"></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="~/Account/Manage.aspx"><i class="icon-pencil"></i>&nbsp;Manage</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="~/Account/Login.aspx"><i class="i"></i>Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the `LoginName` control to do all that for you - just drop it into your MasterPage.